# Existential and universal quantifiers and implication

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

$[p\rightarrow \forall x.P(x)]\equiv \forall x.[p\rightarrow P(x)]$ (1) 
$[(\forall x.P(x))\rightarrow p]\equiv \exists x[P(x)\rightarrow p]$ (2) 
to prove $\exists x \forall y.P(x,y)\rightarrow \forall y\exists x.P(x,y)$ (3)
apply (1) and (2) to $\forall x\forall y[\forall y.P(x,y)\rightarrow \exists x.P(x,y)]$ (4) to prove (3)
where (4) in turn can be deduced from $\forall x.P(x,y)\rightarrow P(x,y)$ and $P(x,y)\rightarrow \exists x.P(x,y)$

I cannot understand how to get (3) out of (1) and (2)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the definition to expression $p\to \forall x.P(x)$? I think you should clarify the notations.

Comment: $p$ doesn't depend on $x$ that is $\forall x.p \equiv p$ and $\exists x.p \equiv p$

Comment: From $[p\rightarrow P(x)]\equiv [\neg p \vee P(x)] \Rightarrow [p→∀x.P(x)]≡∀x.[p→P(x)]  $

Answer (score 1):

It seems I understood: 
$\forall x\forall y[\forall y.P(x,y)\rightarrow \exists x.P(x,y)] = \forall x[\forall y.P(x,y)\rightarrow \forall y \exists x.P(x,y)] = \forall x[\neg\forall y.P(x,y)\vee \forall y \exists x.P(x,y)] = \forall x \neg \forall y.P(x,y)\vee \forall y \exists x.P(x,y) = \neg \exists x \forall y.P(x,y)\vee \forall y \exists x.P(x,y) = \exists x \forall y.P(x,y)\rightarrow \forall y \exists x.P(x,y)$

Answer (score 0):

> apply (1) and (2) to $∀x∀y[∀y.P(x,y)→∃x.P(x,y)]$ (4) to prove (3).

Applying (1), due to the fact that $y$ is not free in $∀y.P(x,y)$, from (4) we get $∀x[∀y.P(x,y)→∀y∃x.P(x,y)]$.

Applying the [Prenex Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication) equivalence: $(\exists x\phi )\rightarrow \psi  \equiv \forall x(\phi \rightarrow \psi )$ to the last formula, due to the fact that $x$ is not free in $∀y∃x.P(x,y)$ we get:

> (3) $\ \ ∃x∀y.P(x,y)→∀y∃x.P(x,y)$.